# Open a modal when input a total number of digits in Ionic 2 Angular 2 how to?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to open a modal when user type in a particular number of digits, but all I have does not look like what I want, instead it fires a modal upon click.

This is what I have done:

**test.html**

```
<ion-card class="card-space">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Amount</ion-label> <!--I can use floating here but I prefer stacked-->
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Input Amount" (itemSelected)="itemClicked($event)">
      </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

**test.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {CompleteTestProvider, ISearch} from "../../providers/complete-test";
import {CustomerDetailsPage} from "../customer-details/customer-details";


@Component({
  selector: 'page-customer-issues-form',
  templateUrl: 'customer-issues-form.html',
})
export class CustomerIssuesFormPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private http: Http,
              public  completeTestProvider: CompleteTestProvider,
              private _modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CustomerIssuesFormPage');
  }

  itemClicked(item: ISearch) {
    console.log(item);
    //so open the modal here
    let modal = this._modalCtrl.create(CustomerDetailsPage, {customer:item});
    modal.present();
  }

}
```

How do I go about this? 
Am using Ionic 2, Angular 2 with Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you can use `ionInput` to execute a function everytime your user inputs a character and passing the `event` as parameter to the function you can get the value and use it to compare. Do as this

Your HTML:

```
<ion-card class="card-space">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Amount</ion-label> <!--I can use floating here but I prefer stacked-->
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Input Amount" (ionInput)="itemClicked($event)">
      </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Your .TS:

```
itemClicked(event: any) {
  // GET THE USER INPUT
  let userInput: string = event.target.value;

  // COMPARE THE LENGTH WITH THE AMOUNT YOU WANT, I'LL USE 10
  if(userInput.length == 10){
    let modal = this._modalCtrl.create(CustomerDetailsPage, {customer:item});
    modal.present(); 
  }
}
```

With this it'll compare with the length you want it to be and open the modal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but an getting error from Typescript Error saying: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using (itemSelected)=, use (input)="itemClicked($event)"
and then you can use $event.target.value to get the value every time it changes. Then when it is the length or value you want, open the modal.

Comment: Can you explain further the `$event.target.value` part of give an example snippet, am Angular 2 virgin @Santiago

Comment: In your method, itemClicked, which will be called multiple times, you should be able to use item.target.value to see the value of your input field to check the length.