# how to open a modal based on irregular digits/length of numbers?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have tried to open a modal based on particular set of numbers input in a form field according to suggested answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46730101/5614748) which works fine for setting just a single length.

But in a case where I want to open a modal upon users entering different length of digits, how do I go about it? *For an example*, some numbers are 10, some are 12, some are 15 numbers, and I must open a modal upon any of those lengths. So if users input 10 digits, or 12 digits, or 15 digits, then any of those 3 lengths must fire a modal. How do I go about it? Am new to Ionic 2, Angular 2 with Typescript.

Here is what I have done:

*user.ts*

```
export class CustomerIssuesFormPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private http: Http,
              public  completeTestProvider: CompleteTestProvider,
              private _modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  // This works but wont deal with what I need
  raiseModal(event: any) {
    let input: string = event.target.value;
    if(input.length == 10){
      let modal = this._modalCtrl.create(CustomerDetailsPage, {customer:event});
      modal.present();
    }
  }
}
```

*user.html*

```
<ion-card class="card-space">
  <ion-item>
     <ion-label stacked >Number</ion-label>
       <ion-input
         type="number"
         (keyup)="raiseModal($event)">
       </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: what issue are you facing with the code?

Comment: @SurajRao am not facing any issue with this code code I posted. Its just not what I want. `What want to be able to open modal if users type in 10 digits, or 12 digits, or 15 digits`, and I do not know how to do it. All am able to do as you can see from the code is being able to open modal only when the input is 10 digits.

Comment: Different number inputs may trigger the modal in different number length? Like input 1 must open modal if 12 digits, input 2 must open if 10 and so on? Or does one input must open a different modal if 10, 12 and then 15 digits in the input?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto it opens the same modal and that model is a response from API the checks users details based on users unique number. Users has different types of account numbers and once they input that account number (which could be either 10, 12, 15 digits), a modal that fetches there details based on the input must open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your case it's a little more complicated, not about programming itself, but because of the UX.

If your user has an account number of 15 digits you don't want him/her to input 10 and open a modal, and then it closes the modal, input 2 more digits and open again, so it closes again and input more 3. So there's a couple of ways to do it:

- When the user leaves (lose focus) on the input.
- When it press `enter`.

The first one you'll use `(blur)` in your html an when the user clicks away from the input you'll call a method to check the account number an open the modal. **But just an obseration:** If the account checking is in an API treat this there and return the component page to open the modal, it's easier and there'll be less code. If it's not coming from an API just use a if/else if/else or a switch/case since there'll be just a few comparisons.

HTML

```
<ion-card class="card-space">
  <ion-item>
     <ion-label stacked >Number</ion-label>
       <ion-input
         type="number"
         (blur)="raiseModal($event)">
       </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

.TS

```
raiseModal(ev: any){
  let input: string = event.target.value;

  if(input.length == 10){
    // OPEN MODAL FOR 10 DIGITS
  } else if (input.length == 12) {
    // OPEN MODAL FOR 12 DIGITS
  } else if (input.length == 15) {
    // OPEN MODAL FOR 15 DIGITS
  } else {
    // ERROR: INPUT LENGTH INVALID
  };
}
```

The second option is just like the first, but you'll have to say to you user to press enter/go on his keyboard so you can check the account info, so you'll get the event in every key entered.

HTML

```
<ion-card class="card-space">
  <ion-item>
     <ion-label stacked>Input number and press 'Enter'</ion-label>
       <ion-input
         type="number"
         (keyup)="raiseModal($event)">
       </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

.TS

```
raiseModal(ev: any){
  let input: string = event.target.value;

  if(ev.keyCode == 13){ // can also be (ev.key == "Enter")
    if(input.length == 10){
      // OPEN MODAL FOR 10 DIGITS
    } else if (input.length == 12) {
      // OPEN MODAL FOR 12 DIGITS
    } else if (input.length == 15) {
      // OPEN MODAL FOR 15 DIGITS
    } else {
      // ERROR: INPUT LENGTH INVALID
    };
  };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much. That helps. blur event is what I will go with. But there is one problem I still face, when the field is empty and user leaves the field, it still fires modal. It shouldn’t fire modal when it’s empty.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi you're welcome. That's why you have that `else` in the end, if it's not 10, 12 or 15 it'll fallback to the `else` and you can just alert or toast that the user needs to input that field.

Comment: I had to pass in `if(input == "" ) {` condition to factor empty field and raise alert if empty, and the `else {`  statement raises modal as is. Thank you so much. You are a life saver.

Comment: What advise or where can you point me to to learn more relating to Angular?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi there's a couple ways you can learn more about Angular, but i would advise you learning JavaScript ES6 better. Then you can go to Angular Docs and start there, their documentation is rich of examples and you can learn so much. If you can afford buy a course on Udemy to study, the platform is great and also the courses there.